# Error loading operating system, Window 8

Tags: windows-8

My windows 8 pc restarted suddenly and then shows an error which says error loading operating system.

After then i restarted my pc again then it takes me to "Recovery mode" saying "The boot configuration data for your PC is missing or contains errors." 
File:\Boot\BCD

Error code:0x000000f

Then i put my windows dvd to reapir it, it asks me what to do:

1. Refresh my pc(files and settings won't be affected)
2. Reset my pc(files will be deleted)

When i click the first one, it says "the drive on which windows is installed is locked, unlock and try again" , but i didn't locked the C: drive.

Then when i click on second one it says "Unable to reset your PC. A required drive partition is missing."

Same problem i faced two weeks ago, i reinstalled windows, with a freshly created partition because when installing on the drive c it says system partion or files corrupted, something like that.

Then i installed Ubuntu, the ubuntu was even worse, crashes often times then i reinstall it, so i switched to windows back but this never solved the problem.

Please tell me a way i can fix this, my system configuration is as follows;

- intel i3 3.2GHz
- 2 GB RAM
- Windows 8 32-bit
- 160 GB HDD (i know it's so small)

Comment: The info is not enough for diagnosis, but it looks like your hard drive is dying.

Comment: @RogUE I did many google searches, it fixes my problem for temporary. That's why im asking here a permanent solution.

Comment: Which fixes found in Google fixed the temporary problem? This information may help us further understand your issue. Also, I agree with the others that it sounds as though your Hard Drive is failing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Most likely the drive is dying. If you have a second computer to connect the drive to, try to write data to it and check the Event Viewer. I am sure you will find Disk Errors.

Comment: I asked my cousin his HDD to check as you said my hard drive is dying, and when i replaced mine with his, i got no success when booting, the bios is saying "please reboot and select a proper boot device" i searched on google found that  could be power cable or data cable's fault which connects the hdd to the motherboard and the PSU.. But my old HDD can be seen when plugged that means cables are working properly. What is going on?? Im so confused.

Comment: You can't take a hard drive with Windows on it from one computer and drop it in an entirely different computer and expect it to boot. Is this why I received negative feedback? You need to reinstall windows on a new hard drive while it is in your computer.

Comment: I thought the same, and tried to install ubuntu, but ubuntu can't find the HDD there, also i didn't downvoted your answer, someone else did, i can't upvote your answer currently but can accept your answer, as i know my hard disk is quite too old, that might be the reason actually, maybe you know better than me, im just gonna buy a new one, and will inform you if that helps, thanks for the help bro.

Answer (score -1):

Try downgrading the windows maybe to Windows 7. If the problem persists, then think no further, just replace the hard disk.

Comment: Downgrading to Windows 7 isn't really a solution to the author's question.

Comment: Yes, @Ramhound is right because when the problem first occured i was using windows 10, then i installed ubuntu, and then windows 8, in short i downgraded from windows 10 to windows 8, but no success.